# PHP Header Location Breaking Google Analytics Goal?

Tags: php, redirect, google-analytics

Our website is currently using Google Universal Analytics to track goal conversions from our own private domain and a 3rd party payment processor. Currently our goal flow is:

`/cart` -> `/checkout` -> `/receipt`

On the `/cart` page which resides on our private domain, the user clicks "checkout". When they do, it goes to `/precheckout` which is a preprocessing script which finishes with `header("Location: external.com/checkout"); exit;`

Our suspicions lead us to believe that it's this intermediary page that is breaking our funnel. From what I understand, when `header("Location: ");` is used and no data is sent to the browser, that it should simply follow the redirect. What is happening?

Comment: Why did you "burninate" header tag? It is clearly relevant. Edit: Ah, I see now. The tag itself is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm willing to bet that the server changing the location is causing the browser to not send the "Referer" header.

Try `header('Referer: /cart');` in the `/checkout`.

Since the user is not clicking on anything in between precheckout and checkout, you need to manually set it. If the user isn't always going to be clicking that link to get to the checkout page (i.e. bookmarking it), it may be better to set a session variable to determine if they just came from the cart and if they did use the header code above.

Comment: I do not have access to server side scripting, only template modifications, once the request leaves `/precheckout`. Are you saying I should do `header("Referer: /cart"); header("Location: external.com/checkout"); exit;` on the `/precheckout` page?

Comment: No, I'm saying that you should put the Referer header on the top of the checkout page. Google uses javascript to track the user, which means that no tracking occurs unless the gag.js file is loaded on the client browser. So the checkout page, which is the next page to load analytics, is the one that needs to know the referer.

Answer (score 0):

The 301 redirect is the preferred way to redirect URLs, since it informs search engines that the URL has moved for good, and search engines should put the new URL page in the search results instead of the old URL page and transfer the new URL page, the page rank of the old URL page.

The 301 redirect can be done across domains or on the same domain.

Google ""analytics"" recommends to use 301 redirect.

```
<?php
// PHP permanent URL redirection
header("Location: http://www.example.com/new-page.php", true, 301);
exit();
?>
```

https://www.rapidtables.com/web/dev/url-redirect.html